# Magento 2: after get qty its show zero always

Tags: magento2, qty

After get qty its show zero always Magento2

[image]

Comment: could you explain it more briefly ?

Comment: i need a qty of products i am using echo $_product->getQty(); to get but on all products its show 0 qty after getting

Comment: in some products i have more then 0 qty but its shows 0 on product page

Comment: i want to get stock of products

Comment: have you tried my below code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below way,

```
echo $_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty();
```

To get product qty in list page, for testing you can use objectmanager after finished testing create this method in helper/block and call that helper/block file from phtml(recommended).

```
$product_Id = $_product->getId();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$stockInfo = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($product_Id);
$stockqty = (int)$stockInfo->getQty();
echo $stockqty;
```

Comment: its working on just product detail page not on product listing page

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getQty() on null in /var/www/html/roykon23/app/design/frontend/Magento/roykon/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml:172 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/roykon23/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59):

Comment: try my updated answer..Instead of using object manager try calling it from custom block

Comment: yes its working thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code - in your phtml file

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
echo $StockState->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
?>
```

** For coding standard keep objectManager in helper class.

Comment: this is shows 0  qty stock on all products on listing page

Comment: Avoid using ObjectManager instead get it through DI