# Magento 2 $data[] = $product->getQty(); Returns 0

Tags: magento2.3, attributes, quantity

Trying to get qty of the simple product for csv.

Using `$data[] = $product->getQty();` but it returns 0. Looks like it returns default value. How to get the actual quantity of the products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a simple product stock Quantity, Refer to the below code.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/StockData.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class StockData extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_stockItemRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getStockItem($productId)
    {
        return $this->_stockItemRepository->get($productId);
    }
}
?>
```

Now you can get quantity in your template file like this.

```
$productStockData = $block->getStockItem($product->getId());
echo $productStockData->getQty();
```

Or you can use objectManager **(Not Preferable)**

```
<?php
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
    $stockItemRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository');
    $productStockData = $stockItemRepository->get($product->getId());
    echo $productStockData->getQty();
?>
```

Comment: The first part of the answer is correct. I wouldn't even suggest using object manager as an alternative. It has never been necessary.

Comment: I copied the first part and it didnt work. I see Error: Call to a member function getQty().

Comment: `$this->_stockItemRepository->get(p1)` parameter seems to be looking for Stock Item ID, not a product ID.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
echo $_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty();
```

[Magento 2: after get qty its show zero always](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287717/magento-2-after-get-qty-its-show-zero-always)